# Change from JS code value in HTML template using # id

Tags: javascript, html

Inside HTML file testFile.html I have this:

```
<div id="image-type-placeholder">marinaa</div>
```

in my js

```
const CourseImageUpload = BaseComponent.extend({



/**
* @property {function}
*/
template: require('testFile.html'),
```

i wanna in js file in initialize function set different values for this HTML id

```
image-type-placeholder
```

do you know how

i tried this:

```
$('#image-type-placeholder').empty().append('testttt');
```

but its not working

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: i dont know, how i can check?

Answer (score 1):

The $ usually marks a jQuery function. If you don't know if jQuery is added to your project then it is likely not.

To target a DOM element by its id, using only javascript (and no jQuery), you can use the `document.getElementById('myId')` function.

In your case, replace

```
$('#image-type-placeholder').empty().append('testttt');
```

by

```
document.getElementById('image-type-placeholder').innerHTML = 'testttt'
```

Comment: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Comment: probably because your js file is loaded before the end of the html file.
Could you try adding the defer attribute where you js script like so: 
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>

Comment: note sure i understand you, where i need to add this?

Comment: In the head of your html script. It hsould look something like this:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> This is head tag java Script file </title>
    <script  type = "text/javascript" src = "yourjsscriptname.js"  defer> </script>
...